How to use enable_if to do template specialisation with indefinite args
What I want to achieve
The motivation is I want to have template with form
template<typename T, typename ...Args>

where T is some class type. And I want a specialised version of this template if T is BaseA or any derived class of BaseA.
(The C++ standard I'm under is C++20)
The problem
If the second template param is definite, this is easy to achieve:
template <typename T, typename U, typename Enable = void>
class Factory
{
    public:
        Factory(U arg)
        {
            m_spInner = std::make_shared<T>(arg);
        }
        void print() const
        {
            printf("Factory normal: ");
            m_spInner->print();
        }
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<T> m_spInner;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
class Factory<T, U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseA, T>::value>::type>
{
public:
    Factory(U arg)
    {
        m_spInner = std::make_shared<T>(arg);
    }
    void print() const
    {
        printf("Factory BaseA: ");
        m_spInner->print();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_spInner;
};

// callers
int main()
{
    Factory<DerivedA1, int> factoryA1(1);
    factoryA1.print();

    Factory<DerivedA2, int> factoryA2(2);
    factoryA2.print();

    Factory<DerivedB, char> factoryB('B');
    factoryB.print();

    Factory<C, string> factoryC("C");
    factoryC.print();

    //Factory<int> factoryInt(1); // compile error
    //factoryInt.print();

    return 0;
}

does the job.
But when the second param is indefinite, like
template <typename T, typename ...Args, typename Enable = void>

it does not compile with error message that the indefinite param must be the last param.
If I put the Enable before the ...Args, the template itself can compile but the calling doesn't work, as int doesn't fit the Enable template param.
So I wonder if it is possible to make enable_if work with class template with indefinite param. Or is there any other elegant way to achieve the need to specialise template for a class and all its child class?
Any suggestion is highly welcomed. Thanks a lot!
Appendix
For convenience, just post my testing code below. If INDEFINITE_PARAM defined, it will compile the INDEFINITE_PARAM version, which lead to error as I couldn't figure out how to properly put enable_if. if INDEFINITE_PARAM not defined, it can compile the definite param version and gives expected result.
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

//#define INDEFINITE_PARAM

using namespace std;


class BaseA
{
public:
    BaseA(int id): m_id(id) {}
    virtual void print() const
    {
        printf("BaseA\n");
    }
private:
    int m_id;
};

class BaseB
{
public:
    BaseB(char id): m_id(id) {}
    virtual void print() const
    {
        printf("BaseB\n");
    }
private:
    char m_id;
};

class DerivedA1 : public BaseA
{
public:
    DerivedA1(int id) : BaseA(id) {}
    void print() const override
    {
        printf("DerivedA1\n");
    }
};

class DerivedA2 : public BaseA
{
public:
    DerivedA2(int id) : BaseA(id) {}
    void print() const override
    {
        printf("DerivedA2\n");
    }
};

class DerivedB : public BaseB
{
public:
    DerivedB(char id) : BaseB(id) {}
    void print() const override
    {
        printf("DerivedB\n");
    }
};

class C
{
public:
    C(string id) : m_id(id) {}
    void print() const
    {
        printf("C\n");
    }
private:
    string m_id;
};

#ifdef INDEFINITE_PARAM

template<typename T, typename Base, typename ...Args>
class Factory
{
public:
    Factory(Args&&... args)
    {
        m_spInner = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    void print() const
    {
        printf("%s\n", typeid(T::Base).name());
        printf("Factory normal: ");
        m_spInner->print();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_spInner;
};


template <typename T, typename ...Args>
class Factory<T, BaseA, Args...>
{
public:
    Factory(Args&&... args)
    {
        m_spInner = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    void print() const
    {
        printf("%s\n", typeid(T::Base).name());
        printf("Factory BaseA: ");
        m_spInner->print();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_spInner;
};


template <typename T, typename... Args>
class Factory<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseA, T>::value, BaseA>::type, Args...>
{
public:
    Factory(Args&&... args)
    {
        m_spInner = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    void print() const
    {
        printf("%s", std::is_base_of<BaseA, T>::value);
        printf("Factory BaseA: ");
        m_spInner->print();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_spInner;
};
/*
template <typename T, typename... Args>
class Factory<T, void, Args...>
{
public:
    Factory(Args&&... args)
    {
        m_spInner = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
    void print() const
    {
        printf("Factory Normal: ");
        m_spInner->print();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_spInner;
};
*/

#else
template <typename T, typename U, typename Enable = void>
class Factory
{
    public:
        Factory(U arg)
        {
            m_spInner = std::make_shared<T>(arg);
        }
        void print() const
        {
            printf("Factory normal: ");
            m_spInner->print();
        }
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<T> m_spInner;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
class Factory<T, U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<BaseA, T>::value>::type>
{
public:
    Factory(U arg)
    {
        m_spInner = std::make_shared<T>(arg);
    }
    void print() const
    {
        printf("Factory BaseA: ");
        m_spInner->print();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> m_spInner;
};
#endif

int main()
{
    Factory<DerivedA1, int> factoryA1(1);
    factoryA1.print();

    Factory<DerivedA2, int> factoryA2(2);
    factoryA2.print();

    Factory<DerivedB, char> factoryB('B');
    factoryB.print();

    Factory<C, string> factoryC("C");
    factoryC.print();

    //Factory<int> factoryInt(1); // compile error
    //factoryInt.print();

    return 0;
}


You use std::enable_if improperly. See notes on cppreference

Which C++ version is your question related?

C++ 20 standard

@3CxEZiVlQ can you be more specified which notes I violated please?

IDK how you can achieve that because Factory<DerivedA1, int> exactly matches template <typename T, typename Base, typename... Args> and template <typename T, typename... Args> is not even considered.

Why do you write variadic class template if Args... pack is only used in constructor? Make ctor variadic. P.S you should make your sample code shorter, it has too much stuff that has nothing to do with question, which nobody wants to delve into.

@3CxEZiVlQ Yes, that's exactly the question. I understand why my version doesn't work, but just cannot figure out a working version.

@Gene The simplified example is just for illustrate the problem. The real case needs to cover the cases that BaseB, BaseC, BaseD which takes arbitrary numbers of args to construct and it is not pre-determined. As for the length of the example, I think I have extracted core part in my question body, the Appendix just provides code that one can copy-paste and compile.

Since C++20, you no longer need Enabler template parameter and std::enable_if/std::void_t (which indeed is not usable with variadic template for class). You can use constraints and subsumption:
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
class Factory
{
    //...
};

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
requires(std::is_base_of<BaseA, T>::value)
class Factory
{
    //...
};

Demo
Note: In your case, the extra Args might just be for the constructor:
template <typename T>
requires(std::is_base_of<BaseA, T>::value)
class Factory<T>
{
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    Factory(Args&&... args)
    {
        m_spInner = std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
// ...
};


Thanks a lot! This is indeed what I need.
